# sed - replacement group in command line double quoted

Tags: command-line, bash, sed

I am trying to run this

```
sed -i -e "s/'(\${RConstants\.staticPath}\/dist\/img\/app\/icons\.svg#[a-z_-]*)'/`\1`/g" test
```

Single quote version

```
sed -i -e 's/'\''(\${RConstants\.staticPath}\/dist\/img\/app\/icons\.svg#[a-z_-]*)'\''/`$1`/g' test
```

Content of test file:

```
useElem.setAttributeNS(null, 'href', '${RConstants.staticPath}/dist/img/app/icons.svg#rsvg__ui--play');    useElem.setAttributeNS(null, 'href', '${RConstants.staticPath}/dist/img/app/icons.svg#rsvg__ui--play');
    useElem.setAttributeNS(null, 'href', '${RConstants.staticPath}/dist/img/app/icons.svg#rsvg__ui--play');
```

Basically I need to replace single quote with back tick.

The problem is that I tried doing the `sed` command with single quotes and with double quotes, each having its own problem.

With double quotes, I'm getting `1: command not found` and with single quotes, it doesn't replace anything.

Answer (score 0):

Problems were 2:

Unescaped backticks (Those are used to spawn a new process)
Unescaped parenthesis, so after fixing the backticks, the error was about not having a capture group.

```
sed -i -e "s/'\(\${RConstants\.staticPath}\/dist\/img\/app\/icons\.svg#[a-z_-]*\)'/\`\1\`/g" test
```

So this worked OK.